# Undefined в парсере

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть код парсера картинок из одной таблице в БД:

```
preg_match_all('/<var class="postImg postImgAligned img-(.*?)" title="(.*?)">.*?<\/var>/', $rowr[$i]['post_html'], $poster, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

И вывод результата:

```
$urlImg = 'images/no_logo.png';

if (@$poster[0][2])
{ 
    $urlImg = $poster[0][2];
}
```

При условии наличия картинки собственно она и показывается, если картинка отсутствует подставляется дефолтная картинка `no_logo.png` и появляется нотис

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in ******\index.php on line 150

150 линия это и есть парсер. Что требуется  дописать, чтобы нотисы не сыпались?

Comment: `@$poster[0][2]` --> `isset($poster[0][2])`?

Comment: Нотисы пропали, но и дефолтные картинки больше не отображаются.

Comment: Исходя из представленного кода такая замена ни как не могла повлиять на исчезновение дефолтовой картинки.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Дефолтные картинки остались как и нотисы. В общем ни чего не изменилось